# Query taking too long - Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, optimization

I am having an issue with the following query returning results a bit too slow and I suspect I am missing something basic.  My initial guess is the 'CASE' statement is taking too long to process its result on the underlying data.  But it could be something in the derived tables as well.

The question is, how can I speed this up?  Are there any glaring errors in the way I am pulling the data?  Am I running into a sorting or looping issues somewhere?  The query runs for about 40 seconds, which seems quite long.  C# is my primary expertise, SQL is a work in progress.

Note I am not asking "write my code" or "fix my code".  Just for a pointer in the right direction, I can't seem to figure out where the slow down occurs.  Each derived table runs very quickly (less than a second) by themselves, the joins seem correct and the result set is returning exactly what I need.  It's just too slow and I'm sure there are better SQL scripter's out there ;) Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
  SELECT 
hdr.taker
, hdr.order_no
, hdr.po_no as display_po
, cust.customer_name
, hdr.customer_id
, 'INCORRECT-LARGE ORDER' + CASE 
                    WHEN (ext_price_calc >= 600.01 and ext_price_calc <= 800) and fee_price.unit_price <>  round(ext_price_calc * -.01,2)
                        THEN '-1%: $' + cast(cast(ext_price_calc * -.01 as decimal(18,2)) as varchar(255))
                    WHEN ext_price_calc >= 800.01 and ext_price_calc <= 1000 and fee_price.unit_price <>  round(ext_price_calc * -.02,2)
                        THEN '-2%: $' + cast(cast(ext_price_calc * -.02 as decimal(18,2)) as varchar(255))
                    WHEN ext_price_calc > 1000 and fee_price.unit_price <>  round(ext_price_calc * -.03,2)
                        THEN '-3%: $' + cast(cast(ext_price_calc * -.03 as decimal(18,2)) as varchar(255))
                    ELSE
                        'OK'
                  END AS Status
FROM
(myDb_view_oe_hdr hdr
LEFT OUTER JOIN myDb_view_customer cust 
ON hdr.customer_id = cust.customer_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN wpd_view_sales_territory_by_customer territory
ON cust.customer_id = territory.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (select
        order_no,
        SUM(ext_price_calc) as ext_price_calc
    from 
    (select
        hdr.order_no,
        line.item_id,
        (line.qty_ordered - isnull(qty_canceled,0)) * unit_price as ext_price_calc 
    from myDb_view_oe_hdr hdr
    left outer join myDb_view_oe_line line
    on hdr.order_no = line.order_no
    where 
        line.delete_flag = 'N'
        AND line.cancel_flag = 'N'
        AND hdr.projected_order = 'N'
        AND hdr.delete_flag = 'N'
        AND hdr.cancel_flag = 'N'
        AND line.item_id not in ('LARGE-ORDER-1%','LARGE-ORDER-2%', 'LARGE-ORDER-3%', 'FUEL','NET-FUEL', 'CONVENIENCE-FEE')) as line
    group by order_no)  as order_total
    on hdr.order_no = order_total.order_no
 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (select 
        order_no,
        count(order_no) as convenience_count
    from oe_line with (nolock)
    left outer join inv_mast inv with (nolock)
    on oe_line.inv_mast_uid = inv.inv_mast_uid
    where inv.item_id in ('LARGE-ORDER-1%','LARGE-ORDER-2%', 'LARGE-ORDER-3%')
        and oe_line.delete_flag <> 'Y'
    group by order_no) as fee_count
on hdr.order_no = fee_count.order_no
INNER JOIN 
    (select 
        order_no, 
        unit_price 
    from oe_line line with (nolock) 
    where line.inv_mast_uid in (select inv_mast_uid from inv_mast with (nolock) where item_id in ('LARGE-ORDER-1%','LARGE-ORDER-2%', 'LARGE-ORDER-3%'))) as fee_price
ON fee_count.order_no = fee_price.order_no
WHERE
    hdr.projected_order = 'N'
    AND hdr.cancel_flag = 'N'
    AND hdr.delete_flag = 'N'
    AND hdr.completed = 'N'
    AND territory.territory_id = ‘CUSTOMERTERRITORY’
    AND ext_price_calc > 600.00
    AND hdr.carrier_id <> '100004'
    AND fee_count.convenience_count is not null
    AND CASE 
            WHEN (ext_price_calc >= 600.01 and ext_price_calc <= 800) and fee_price.unit_price <>  round(ext_price_calc * -.01,2)
                THEN '-1%: $' + cast(cast(ext_price_calc * -.01 as decimal(18,2)) as varchar(255))
            WHEN ext_price_calc >= 800.01 and ext_price_calc <= 1000 and fee_price.unit_price <>  round(ext_price_calc * -.02,2)
                THEN '-2%: $' + cast(cast(ext_price_calc * -.02 as decimal(18,2)) as varchar(255))
            WHEN ext_price_calc > 1000 and fee_price.unit_price <>  round(ext_price_calc * -.03,2)
                THEN '-3%: $' + cast(cast(ext_price_calc * -.03 as decimal(18,2)) as varchar(255))
            ELSE
                'OK' END <> 'OK'
```

Comment: I notice a lot of left outer joins on views.  Views in joins often do not allow the database engine to take advantage of indices.  That is one place to start looking.

Comment: You can use EXPLAIN keyword to see where your query has bottleneck during the execution. You can put EXPLAIN keyword in front of the query and it will show the bottleneck points. Then you can work on that points.

Comment: @David Fleeman: they are not views but nested queries

Comment: Can we create a flag for these "optimize this specific query" questions to move them to codereview.stackexchange.com ? Just look at that title. How will this question be helpful to anyone in the future?

Comment: And I don't mean that this question is bad or doesn't need attention, it's just not very good for StackOverflow, is all.

Comment: @KyleHale I did post this on code review, but the comments/answers were poor at best.  I will agree that this isn't an SO friendly question.  My apologies.

Comment: Definitely not your fault, you did what you thought was best. I will raise something on meta about this.

Comment: @zerkms - I believe these are both views: myDb_view_oe_hdr and wpd_view_sales_territory_by_customer.

Comment: @DavidFleeman You are correct.  Taking them out sped me up quite a bit.  The question then becomes, why are views in sub-queries ignoring indexes on the underlying tables. (The views select from tables)  But I digress... that would be a different research question and I'm sure there are answers already out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a clue to the right direction for optimization:

- When you do an OUTER JOIN to a query with calculated columns, you are guaranteeing not only a full table scan, but that those calculations must be performed against every row in the joined table.   It appears that you can actually do your join to oe_line without the column calculations (i.e. by filtering **ext_price_calc** to a specific range).
- You don't need to do most of the subqueries that are in your query--the master query can be recrafted to use regular table join  syntax.   Joins to subqueries containing subqueries presents a challenge to the SQL optimizer that it may not be able to meet.   But by using regular joins, the optimizer has a much better chance at identifying more efficient query strategies.
- You don't tag which SQL engine you're using.   Every database has proprietary extensions that may allow for speedier or more efficient queries.   It would be easier to provide useful feedback if you indicated whether you were using MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.
- Regardless of the database you're using, reviewing the query plan is always a good place to start.    This will tell you where most of the I/O and time in your query is being spent.
- Just on general principle, make sure your statistics are up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

It's may not be solvable by any of us without the real stuff to test with.

IF that's the case and nobody else posts the answer, I can still help. Here is how to trouble shoot it.

(1) take joins and pieces out one by one.
   (2) this will cause errors. Remove or fake the references to get rid of them.
(3) see how that works.
(4) Put items back before you try taking something else out
(5) keep track...
(6) also be aware where a removal of something might drastically reduce the result set.

You might find you're missing an index or some other smoking gun.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and I was able to solve it by indexing one of the tables and setting a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the problem lies in the number of joins you're doing.  A lot of databases do joins basically by systemically checking all possible combinations of the various tables as being valid - so if you're joinging table A and B on column C, and A looks like:
Name:C
Fred:1
Alice:2
Betty:3

While B looks like:
C:Pet
1:Alligator
2:Lion
3:T-Rex

When you do the join, it checks all 9 possibilities:
Fred:1:1:Alligator
Fred:1:2:Lion
Fred:1:3:T-Rex
Alice:2:1:Alligator
Alice:2:2:Lion
Alice:2:3:T-Rex
Betty:3:1:Alligator
Betty:3:2:Lion
Betty:3:3:T-Rex

And goes through and deletes the non-matching ones:
Fred:1:1:Alligator
Alice:2:2:Lion
Betty:3:3:T-Rex

... which means with three entries in each table, it creates nine temporary records, sorts through them all, and deletes six of them ... all before it actually sorts through the results for what you're after (so if you are looking for Betty's Pet, you only want one row on that final result).

... and you're doing how many joins and sub-queries?

Comment: "problem lies in the number of joins you're doing" --- it's definitely wrong. 10 joins cannot be the issue by themselves.

Comment: @zerkms You are definitely right.  I am using no more joins than absolutely necessary, and I have other queries that run 10 times faster that have many more complex joins than this one.